# Kendo UI Grid validation when creating a new row

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Currently I'm looking to validate new created row before saving changes,
schema is not working to enforce the rules on the created row.
I need to let the user know what fields are required if he tried to save with an error message.

This example has already custom validation ,you can see it in the schema ,the problem it's not forcing validation before submitting to the server.

```
var gResult = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    read:,
    update:,
    create:,
     schema: {
            model: {
                    id: "Id",
                    fields: {
                    Id: { type: 'number' },
                    Color: { type: 'string', defaultValue: "#000" },
                    Name: {type: 'string', validation: { required: true } },
                    Address1: { validation: { required: true } },
                    City: { validation: { required: true } },
                    Country: { validation: { required: true }, defaultValue: "Deutchland" },
                    PostalCode: { type: 'number', validation: { required: true } },
                    Emails: {
                        type: 'string',
                        validation: {

                            required: { message: "Email ID Required." },
                            validateEmailFormat: function (input) {
                                if (input.attr("data-bind") == "value:Email") {
                                    input.attr("data-validateEmailFormat-msg", "Email format invalid.");
                                    return checkEmail(input.val());
                                }
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

    });

      $("#gridResult").kendoGrid({

            columns: GridColumns.Columns,
            dataSource: gResult,
            navigatable: true,
            sortable: true,
            height: 1000,
            filterable: true,
            pageable: GridProp.Pageable,
            editable: true, toolbar: ["create", "save"] });
```

Comment: Take a look at [this example for setting up custom validation](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-custom-validation)

Comment: This example has already custom validation ,you can see it in the schema ,the problem it's not forcing validation before submitting to the server.@Sandman

Comment: Helllllp!!!! SOS i have the same problem